# How to download from a href after waiting for a site to load with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

**Background:**

I have a bit of Python Selenium code that waits for the website to load (it's got a delay). Once the website is loaded I want to click/download the link from the href.

Python Selenium:

```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/full/path/to/chromedriver.exe')

   browser.get(MAIN_WEBSITE + pdf)
   delay = 20 # seconds
   try:
       myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn-group']")))
       print("Page is ready!")
       # Now the site is loaded - I can download the pdf - but I am stuck!

   except TimeoutException:
       print("Loading took too much time!")
```

HTML CODE after it's been loaded

```
<div class="btn-group">
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-user" onclick="AiD('182030801')" href="/download.pdf?id=182030801&amp;h=917901e6659ad5eb53970aecf687b53e&amp;u=cache&amp;ext=pdf" target="_blank" style="border-top-left-radius: 3px;border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;">
[...]
</div>
```

**Question:**

I want to get selenium to 'click & download' the pdf associated with the `href` link. How cand I do this?

**References:**

- [YouTube: Selenium Webdriver - Download File](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5xwLr3xYiI)

**What I have tried - and still can't make it work**:

```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/full/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
   browser.get(MAIN_WEBSITE + pdf)
   delay = 20 # seconds
   try:
       myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn-group']")))
       print("Page is ready!")
       # Now the site is loaded - I can download the pdf - but I am stuck!

   except TimeoutException:
       print("Loading took too much time!")

   browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn-group']/a").click()
```

Comment: Xpath needs an /a and a .click() at the end.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I realized that - changed/updated the code - but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Might need to just use myElem.getAttribute('href') instead in conjuction with the driver.current_url.

Comment: Just driver.get(driver.current_url+myElem.getAttribute('href')) Then click the download link after.

Comment: @arundeepchohan `print(myElem.getAttribute('href'))
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'` :/

Comment: Probably easier if you just post a code snippet as an answer!

Comment: @arundeepchohan print("myElem: ", myElem) is `myElem:   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ea7998d51af01354942ad5760246fa7d", element="1ef501a7-36da-4aeb-bc16-3625dab2decb")>`

Answer (score 0):

Using something like this to get pdf page link.

```
import urllib

try:
     myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn-group']/a")))
     urllib.retrieve(driver.current_url+myElem.get_attribute('href'))     
except TimeoutException:
   print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Comment: I don't think urllib has urlretrieve any longer... it's been [depricated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), also I think it will be better if I `.click()` the button....

Comment: the .click() has a click action though.

Comment: onclick="AiD('182030801')"

Comment: I can't really test though so try it out.